# How do I work out how large a cake tin I have?

Tags: baking, measurements

I am making a cake and the recipe calls for a 900g/2lb loaf tin. How do I work out if the loaf tin I have is the correct size - or how do I work out how big my tin is so I know whether to scale the recipe appropriately?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at a 8.5" x 4.5" x 2.5" (or 7.25" x 4.5" x 3.5", high sided model) bread pan.  If you are looking at using a different shape, it might affect the texture of the cake, but you'll have to calculate the volume difference from there.  Something around 100-114 cubic inches. (Length x width x height).

Comment: I'm curious where the 2lb designation came from - what sort of bread weighs two pounds in a loaf that size?

Comment: from what I read, I didn't see that this size bread pan is a 2lb pan.  One with with the same width and length but 3 inches in depth is listed as a 1 lb. pan (http://www.amazon.com/USA-Pans-Aluminized-Steel-Americoat/dp/B0029JQEIC).  I saw 10" x 5" x 3" as a 2 lb. pan.  I've personally only ever made 2 lb. loaves in a bread machine.

Comment: The key is the 900g pan, which is not how we measure, but the whole English side of the world.  If you look at pans from there you find that is a standard size for their pans.  http://bakerybits.co.uk/Traditional-2lb-or-900g-Loaf-Tin-P1499161.aspx is a good example.  Hopefully that will help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the answer is to use a conversion chart.  Google provides many, but [this one](http://allrecipes.com//HowTo/cake-pan-size-conversions/Detail.aspx) is specific to cake pans.

In your case, though, the weight measurement is pretty non-standard.  Pan conversion charts usually do things by volume.  Assuming, though, a fluid ounces conversion where 8 fl. oz. is one cup, you want a 32 ounce pan, or 4 cup pan.  The conversion chart will show you a variety of 4 cup pans, and also how many cups your cake tin holds, then convert that to fl. oz. and scale.